# Add content to table cell using .css file

Tags: html, css, html-table

I would like to add content to table cells using .css file. The needed scenario is that when your (pc) mouse gets over the cell (:hover) the smiley face symbol (f.e. ☺) should appear in the cell.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Hi @Paulie_D, I don´t need any code from you, I already have my own, all I need is just a tag or command that will set content of my cell to something, f.e. to smiley face...that´s all ;) :)

Comment: We'd like to see some of that code you claim to have. Perhaps some where you've attempted to use the `:hover` pseudo-selector to make a smiley face appear? Or perhaps links to some Stack Overflow questions you've seen in your research that were close?

Comment: Alright guys, I will go slow on you, I posted this question, because I wasn´t able to find another same or nearly close question, is it clear now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a pseudo element on each td when it is hovered which puts the smiley over the contents of the cell.

Note this is not putting content into the cell, it just visually looks like that.

```css
td {
  height: 10vmin;
  width: 10vmin;
  border: solid 1px black;
  position: relative;
}

td:hover::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fw13s.png');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<h3>Hover over any cell</h3>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Cool, nice and clean way how to achieve my goal, thanks! :O